# Moving field content to new field collection fields automatically

Tags: 7, entities

I'm working on existing site which has small boxes with an image, title & text in them multiple times on a page. Currently it uses fields for each one so there'll be six image fields, six title fields, etc but I'd like to making them all one field in a field collection which can be added multiple times.

Creating the new field collection an appropriate fields is fine but what is the best way of moving the existing multiple field images, titles, etc to the field collection?

Comment: you mean you don't want lost fields data?

Comment: @zhilevan yes, I'd like to transfer the data from the current fields E.G `field_image1`, `field_image2`, etc into just the new `field_image_collection` which will be a repeatable field.

Comment: I did something like that 2-3 years ago, but it needs some custom code and at this time I don't have active drupal 7 with Field_collection and data to test it :(. just could give you a  summary of the solution.

Comment: @zhilevan A summary would certainly be helpful as I currently only have a vague idea that it'll either involve using the fields API or a fair amount of SQL (which probably isn't the recommended way).

Comment: ok, how many nodes do you have in that content type?

Comment: @zhilevan The Content Type has a over 100 pages published & there are 3 separate fields currently duplicated 6 times each, so there's 6 image fields, 6 title fields & 6 description fields.

Comment: Ok, I provide a summary of what you have to do to achieve that, I hope it could help you to proceed.

Comment: What about Rules to create new field collection items and VBO to trigger the rule for each node?

Comment: @NiallMurphy I've not made use of those modules before but know of them. I'll try that first and see how it goes, if you want to elaborate on that as an answer I can accept it if it works.

Comment: In rules, you would create a rule for when a node is updated, add some "entity has field" conditions so the data is available and for actions, create new entity>field collection item and use data from the existing node.

Comment: Then use VBO to bulk update the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

- Create your Field collection,
- Add new fields to it
- Add field Collection Field To your content type
- Create a Custom module ( if you don't have)
- With Getting help of [Batch Operation Docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/batch-api/overview), Create A Batch Operations on your desired content type
- On each epic load node, get your fields data,
- Add those values to field collection ( [add an item at field collection programmatically](https://www.drupal.org/node/1106182#comment-4653514))
- Check the Results
- remove old fields from the content type

**I Strongly Recommend befor write batch, try it on one node, I mean create a route ( I mean item with hook_menu) then in call back try to achieve what you want, after success convert it to a batch operation or do it with VBO + Php Filter module(instead of batch processing)**

Comment: I'm going to read through the documentation and see if this will do what I need, thanks for the answer.